# Can you use multiple conditions in match() function - R

Tags: r

I'm trying to graph excess deaths for 2020 against confirmed covid-19 deaths.

I have 2 dataframes, one x_worldwide_weekly_deaths (covid-19) and the other containing excess deaths, I want to add an excess deaths column to x_worldwide_weekly_deaths and match by both ISO3 country code, and week number;

Not every country tracks excess deaths so I want those not within the original excess df to have an NA value

Likewise, not every country who track excess deaths are as up to date, some have 37 weeks of data, others might only have 24, so I want the NA values for the missing weeks also

Using the below, I've gotten halfway there, countries not on the original list have NA and those who are have a value, however it only uses the first value rather than changing total per week

```
x_worldwide_weekly_death_values["excess_2020"] <- excess_death_2020$DTotal[match(x_worldwide_weekly_death_values$ISO3,
                                                         excess_death_2020$ISO3)]
```

Example of the data not in the original excess_death_2020 file which have had NA's added successfully

```
 ISO3  administrative_~ population pop_density_km2 week_number weekly_deaths date       excess_2020
   <chr> <chr>                 <int> <chr>                 <dbl>         <dbl> <date>           <dbl>
 1 AFG   Afghanistan        37172386 56.937760009803           1             0 2020-01-06          NA
 2 AFG   Afghanistan        37172386 56.937760009803           2             0 2020-01-13          NA
 3 AFG   Afghanistan        37172386 56.937760009803           3             0 2020-01-20          NA
```

dput() for the above:

```
dput(x_worldwide_weekly_death_values[1:3,])
structure(list(ISO3 = c("AFG", "AFG", "AFG"), administrative_area_level_1 = c("Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), population = c(37172386L, 37172386L, 
37172386L), pop_density_km2 = c("56.937760009803", "56.937760009803", 
"56.937760009803"), week_number = c(1, 2, 3), weekly_deaths = c(0, 
0, 0), date = structure(c(18267, 18274, 18281), class = "Date"), 
    excess_2020 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Compared to Austria, where the week 1 value has been added to all cells

```
  ISO3  administrative_a~ population pop_density_km2 week_number weekly_deaths date       excess_2020
  <chr> <chr>                  <int> <chr>                 <dbl>         <dbl> <date>           <dbl>
1 AUT   Austria              8840521 107.1279668605~           1             0 2020-01-06        1610
2 AUT   Austria              8840521 107.1279668605~           2             0 2020-01-13        1610
3 AUT   Austria              8840521 107.1279668605~           3             0 2020-01-20        1610
```

dput() for the above:

```
dput(x_worldwide_weekly_death_values[371:373,])
structure(list(ISO3 = c("AUT", "AUT", "AUT"), administrative_area_level_1 = c("Austria", 
"Austria", "Austria"), population = c(8840521L, 8840521L, 8840521L
), pop_density_km2 = c("107.127966860564", "107.127966860564", 
"107.127966860564"), week_number = c(1, 2, 3), weekly_deaths = c(0, 
0, 0), date = structure(c(18267, 18274, 18281), class = "Date"), 
    excess_2020 = c(1610, 1610, 1610)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Expected output for excess_2020 column would be the DTotal column figures associated to the Week number; Week 1 = 1610, Week 2 = 1702, Week 3 = 1797

```
  ISO3   Year  Week Sex   D0_14 D15_64 D65_74 D75_84  D85p DTotal   R0_14  R15_64 R65_74 R75_84  R85p
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 AUT    2020     1 b         1    220    221    481   687   1610 4.07e-5 0.00196 0.0134 0.0399 0.157
2 AUT    2020     2 b         8    231    261    490   712   1702 3.26e-4 0.00206 0.0158 0.0407 0.163
3 AUT    2020     3 b        12    223    272    537   753   1797 4.89e-4 0.00198 0.0165 0.0446 0.173
```

dput() for the above

```
dput(excess_death_2020[1:3,])
structure(list(ISO3 = c("AUT", "AUT", "AUT"), Year = c(2020, 
2020, 2020), Week = c(1, 2, 3), Sex = c("b", "b", "b"), D0_14 = c(1, 
8, 12), D15_64 = c(220, 231, 223), D65_74 = c(221, 261, 272), 
    D75_84 = c(481, 490, 537), D85p = c(687, 712, 753), DTotal = c(1610, 
    1702, 1797), R0_14 = c(4.07296256273503e-05, 0.000325837005018803, 
    0.000488755507528204), R15_64 = c(0.00195783568851069, 0.00205572747293622, 
    0.00198453344789947), R65_74 = c(0.0133964529296798, 0.0158211502925177, 
    0.0164879420672982), R75_84 = c(0.0399495248686277, 0.0406970211759409, 
    0.044600613003021), R85p = c(0.157436284517545, 0.163165406952681, 
    0.172561167746305), RTotal = c(0.00948052042945739, 0.0100222644539978, 
    0.0105816740445559), Split = c(0, 0, 0), SplitSex = c(0, 
    0, 0), Forecast = c(1, 1, 1), date = structure(c(18267, 18274, 
    18281), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried a few variations of the below with little success

```
x_worldwide_weekly_deaths["excess_2020"] <- excess_death_2020$DTotal[excess_death_2020$Week[match(x_worldwide_weekly_death_values$week_number
                                         [x_worldwide_weekly_death_values$ISO3],
                                         excess_death_2020$Week[excess_death_2020$CountryCode])]]
```

Should I not be using match() on multiple criteria or am I not formatting it correctly?

Really appreciate any help and suggestions!

Comment: Please provide `dput()` output for each of the example datasets you're sharing.  Also, post expected output - this will help verify solutions.

Comment: Yes please to sharing your data but also while it is possible to use `match` this is likely more a candidate for `merge` see `?merge` for how to use it

Comment: have a look at `dplyr::left_join()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr` is reaaly good/easy for this kind of thing. Here's a simplified example that achieves both of your goals (adding `NA` for countries that are not in the excess death data, and adding `NA` for weeks that are not in the excess death data)...

```r
library(dplyr)

x_worldwide_weekly_death_values <-
  tribble(
    ~iso3c, ~week, ~covid_deaths,
    "AFG",      1,            0,
    "AFG",      2,           10,
    "AFG",      3,           30,
    "AFG",      4,           50,
    "AUT",      1,          120,
    "AUT",      2,          200,
    "AUT",      3,          320,
    "AUT",      4,          465,
    "XXX",      1,           10,
    "XXX",      2,           20,
    "XXX",      3,           30,
    "XXX",      4,           40,
  )

excess_death_2020 <- 
  tribble(
    ~iso3c, ~week, ~DTotal,
    "AFG",      1,       0,
    "AFG",      2,       0,
    "AFG",      3,       0,
    "AUT",      1,       1610,
    "AUT",      2,       1702,
    "AUT",      3,       1797,
    
  )

x_worldwide_weekly_death_values %>% 
  left_join(excess_death_2020, by = c("iso3c", "week"))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    iso3c  week covid_deaths DTotal
#>    <chr> <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 AFG       1            0      0
#>  2 AFG       2           10      0
#>  3 AFG       3           30      0
#>  4 AFG       4           50     NA
#>  5 AUT       1          120   1610
#>  6 AUT       2          200   1702
#>  7 AUT       3          320   1797
#>  8 AUT       4          465     NA
#>  9 XXX       1           10     NA
#> 10 XXX       2           20     NA
#> 11 XXX       3           30     NA
#> 12 XXX       4           40     NA
```

Comment: Thanks CJ! Managed to get it sorted with a left_join after Richard's comment, gutted I spent so long trying to make the match() do what I want! But thanks for your answer that's a lot more learnable than I would have been able to add!