# What does tibble in R exactly do?

Tags: r, function

I came accross this question: [Can you use multiple conditions in match() function - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982263/can-you-use-multiple-conditions-in-match-function-r), and I was wondering, what exacly is the tribble function used for? (It's part of the answer provided)

According to Rdocumentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/3.0.4/topics/tribble) it is used to constuct dataframes, but what is the difference between it and e.g. `data.frame()` ?

Comment: Create tibbles using an easier to read row-by-row layout. This is useful for small tables of data where readability is important. Please see tibble-package for a general introduction. from the [docs](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tribble.html) also you're linking to the documentation of `tibble` while actually asking about the function `tribble`

Comment: For simple datasets, why not just run both functions and see which output format you prefer?

Comment: Unfortunately my dataset is quite large and I was wondering why this method was preferred in the example I mentioned. But thank you for the recommendation, I will give it a go with dummy data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Tibble Vs data.frame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qHdqWx-vsQ)**

The below information will give you a better understanding of how tibble differs from data.frame

|  | Tibble | data.frame |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row names | doesn't add row names to the data frame | Can add row names |
| partial matching of variable name | Doesn't allow partial matching of variable name | permitted |
| Subset | subsetting/extracting part of a tibble always gives a tibble | subsetting data.frame can return vector |
| non-valid R variable | Allows non-valid R variable names | A non-valid R variable name has to be surrounded by backticks |
| variables | variables used to create tibble must have same length | can have different length |
| recycling values of vector | Tibbles don't recycle values of vector when creating dataframe | data.frame recycles values of vector when creating a dataframe |
| Printing capabilities | has better printing capabilities | no special printing capabilities |
| Printing rows | can specify no of rows to print for a tibble | prints all rows |
| Printing columns | Only prints number of columns that can fit horizontally in console | prints all columns |